# Forward vs backward formulation in Feynman-Kac

Tags: partial-differential-equations, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ be a nice filtered probability space with an $m$-dimensional standard Brownian motion $W$. Fix a time horizon $T>0$. Let $\mu \colon [0,T] \times \mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^d$ and $\sigma \colon [0,T] \times \mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{d \times m}$ be nice.
Let $X^{t_0,x}$ be the stochastic process that solves the SDE
$$ X_t^{t_0,x} = x + \int_{t_0}^t \mu_s(X_s^{t_0,x}) ds + \int_{t_0}^t \sigma_s(X_s^{t_0,x}) dW_s $$
with initial condition $X_{t_0}^{t_0,x} = x$ at time $t_0$.
The generator of this SDE is
$$ L_tf(x) = \nabla f(x)^T \mu_t(x) + \frac{1}{2} \mathrm{trace}(\sigma_t(y)\sigma_t(y)^T\nabla^2f(x)). $$
The Feynman-Kac formula in backwards formulation states that the function
$$ u_t(x) = \mathbb{E}[f(X_T^{t,x})] $$
solves the PDE
$$ \partial_t u_t(x) = -L_tu_t(x) $$
with *terminal* condition $u_T(x) = f(x)$.
The forward formulation states that
$$ v_t(x) = \mathbb{E}[f(X_t^{0,x})] $$
solves the PDE
$$ \partial_t v_t(x) = L_tv_t(x) $$
with *initial* condition $v_0(x) = f(x)$.

On the level of PDEs, it is intuitive and easy to see how the forward and backward formulations interact, namely $u_t(x) = v_{T-t}(x)$.
On the level of SDEs, there is also a clear conceptual analogy between
$$ X_T^{t,x} = x + \int_t^T \mu_s(X_s^{t,x}) ds + \int_t^T \sigma_s(X_s^{t,x}) dW_s \qquad\qquad (1) $$
and
$$ X_t^{0,x} = x + \int_0^t \mu_s(X_s^{0,x}) ds + \int_0^t \sigma_s(X_s^{0,x}) dW_s. \qquad\qquad (2) $$
However, I struggle to grasp the direct link between these two formulations on the level of SDEs.
More precisely, it follows from $u_t(x) = v_{T-t}(x)$ that
$$ \mathbb{E}[f(X_T^{t,x})] = \mathbb{E}[f(X_{T-t}^{0,x})]. \qquad\qquad(3) $$
But the process $t \mapsto X_{T-t}^{0,x}$ is not even $\mathcal{F}$-adapted.
So, **question number 1**: is there an intuition and a proof for (3) without arguing via the PDEs?

Further, many other results in stochastic analysis are formulated for processes of the form (1) and it seems to me that they are, at least formally, not directly applicable to processes of the form (2).
Therefore, **question number 2**: why would I use the backward formulation? I can use the forward formulation instead, where all the other machinery is applicable, and then convert to the backward formulation at the very end. Are there any advantages/disadvantages that I am missing?

Cheers!

EDIT: I have received some helpful remarks from a colleague, reflected in my last comment below. Let me redirect the question a bit based on those. You may focus your attention on this edit, but any additional input to the original question is also highly appreciated!

I was mislead to believe that the so-called forward formulation acctually holds also in the case of time-dependent coefficients. Thus, in the time-dependent case, both questions 1 and 2 as posed above seemingly end up being void.

In the time-independent case, Bart and Sebastian in the comments have pointed in the right direction to understand (3). I understand the idea of their solution and can give an informal argument to support it, but this informal argument is based on a non-rigorous time-change in the Ito integral. I would appreciate any pointers to a very rigorous discussion of this time-homogeneity (textbook or directly as an answer).

Question 2 for the time-independent case still stands in a slightly different way: the proof I have seen for the (backward) Feynman-Kac formula involves the flow property of $X^{t_0,x}_t$. I do not see how the proof would go through for the forward version. So, is there a direct proof of the forward version or does one have to first prove the backward version and then use (3)? (Instead of going the other way around and deducing (3) from the assumed validity of both Feynman-Kac formulas as I had done above.)

Comment: As for your 1st question, on a purely intuitive level $\mu$ and $\sigma$ are time-independent, hence one may expect $X$ to satisfy a time invariance: shifting $X^{0,x}_{T-t}$ over a time interval of length $t$ to $X^{t,x}_T$ should not change its distribution.

Comment: The equality (3) is because $X$ is a time-homogeneous Markov process.

Comment: Thank you both for your comment. Tbh, I didn't think too much about the case with $\mu$ and $\sigma$ time-independent. In my context, they actually do depend on time. I merely neglected the time-dependence in the question for the sake of presentation, not realizing that it makes quite a difference.

Comment: Just curious about your notation: you introduce the functions $\mu$ and $\sigma$ at the beginning but later you write $\mu_s(X_s)$. What does that mean? is $\mu_s(X_s)$ another way of writing  $\mu(s,X_s)$?

Comment: Yes, I should have clarified that I write $\mu_s(x)$ for $\mu(s,x)$.

Comment: I don't think equality (3) holds if $\mu$ depends explicitly on $s$, but I am not sure. So let's see what people that know have to say.

Comment: I just realized that I may be misinformed as to the validity of what I called the forward formulation of Feynman-Kac. If $\mu$ and $\sigma$ are time-independent, then (3) holds as pointed out by Bart and Sebastian. In particular, the forward formulation holds a posteriori in this case. For time-dependent $\mu$ and $\sigma$, could it be that neither (3) nor the forward formulation are valid in general? Question 2 then becomes redundant for the time-dependent case.

Comment: Nice might be a city in france or as found by duckduckgo some mathematics group at a university of a company. Even informal problems have limits. Reference such definitions for example to [nice functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/764354/nice-functions) to figure this informally at best.